# ios9: detect if notification is received by the device

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, remote-notifications

Aim:I want to use the notification data upon receiving a notification on the device.
I implemented methods

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler

(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken
```

I can see actionable buttons on the notification and when a button is clicked, I come to know that an action has been taken.

Also implemented

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {}
```

but upon receiving the notification, this method is not executed.

Is there any limitation in ios9 and below?